# Trying to generate images through Fractal DB but came across this issue

Tags: python, numpy

This is the complete code https://hirokatsukataoka16.github.io/Pretraining-without-Natural-Images/
and I am trying to make this part of the code run. https://github.com/hirokatsukataoka16/FractalDB-Pretrained-ResNet-PyTorch/blob/main/fractal_renderer/make_fractaldb.py. When I try to run this part of the code it gives me "An exception has occurred" error like shown in the images below.

kind of lost here. I do not know what the issue is.